# ValueError: Operator string 'array_contains' is invalid

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python (firebase_admin) package to run a script to fill my firestore database with data.

And when I run this following query:

```
search_releases = self.db.collection('new_search').where(u'm_y_filters', u'array_contains', month_year).get()
```

I get this following error:

```
ValueError: Operator string 'array_contains' is invalid. Valid choices are: <, <=, ==, >, >=.
```

Why is this? Is there something wrong with array_contains?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that you should user 'array-contains' instead.